# How to install tile over area with no drywall

Tags: tile

[image]Plumbers made a mistake by placing a mixer vertically when it was supposed to be horizontal. I had to remove 3 tiles and some cement board in order to the mixer. Now what everything has been positioned properly, there is no base to install the tile onto. What can I use to create a base for tile installation? Foam?

Comment: I posted the picture. To install the cement board I would need to remove more tiles.

Comment: Foam? face->desk. The substrate for tile *'is everything'*.

Comment: The plumber made a mistake, so why is the plumber not fixing it all ?  (or paying for it to be done properly by a pro )

Answer (score 6):

Patch the hole with cement board. This may require removing addition tiles and cutting more cement board to reveal half a stud on the right and most of a stud on the left  but it will be a better solution then a quick fix. Once you have the cement board make sure adequate waterproofing, per regulation where you live, is also done. Then re-tile.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Don't short change your fix or you'll be making a mistake like the plumbers did

Comment: This is a good start, but IMO the entire wall is not salvageable. If you could tear out everything on that wall but leave what's in the corner and add a stud then you'd be able to preserve the wraparound of the waterproof membrane when you re-apply (assuming that's what the blue stuff is).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it seems like removing one or two more tiles and having a clean go at it would be the easiest approach. If you have the tile available, I'd do that. The time spent flopping those tiles back on is saved by not having to jigsaw-puzzle your way back to a good base.

Otherwise...

1. Clean up the mangled cement board to achieve straight, square cuts. Use an angle grinder with a diamond wheel and a shop vac. Where possible, center these cuts over framing. Try to leave existing board protruding from behind the remaining tiles (don't cut it flush) so you can patch to it later.
2. Add framing blocking where needed. You don't need to support every single edge and corner. Hit a few key points. The tile will span the joints and lend its own support as well. Pre-drill the blocks for screws and use construction adhesive for extra stability.
3. Patch in the cement board. Be careful not to crack things up by placing screws in delicate areas. You could go so far as to pilot for the screws.
4. Using tile mortar and fiberglass tape, join the panels as you would drywall. This will help stabilize the edges. Keep the joint repair as thin as possible to not complicate tile installation.
5. Install the tile as before.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to reclad the bath wall is to remove the old tiles of that wall. Then fix a Granite slab - prepolished or with antic/ laetherd finish - with glass stud or dry lading. Seal the joint with epoxy sealent. This will add the beauty to bath room